# computing $\int_{[a,b]}g^\sigma\mathrm{d}g$ for the increasing & continuous function $g$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I encountered this question in Makarov & Podkorytov, Real analysis.

I need to show that for an increasing and continuous function $g$ defined on $[a,b]$ the following formula holds $$\int_{[a,b]}g^\sigma\mathrm{d}g = \frac{g^{\sigma+1}(b)-g^{\sigma+1}(a)}{\sigma+1}$$ for every $\sigma>0$.

I'm having difficulties proving this. Using the definintion of lebesgue integration one can show that this term is from above and below by similar riemann-stieltjes integrals, but this seems like a messy approach, since i think this question is still very well contained within the theory of lebesgue integration.

Any hints are appreciated, but i am looking for an approach which is more lebesgue-integration oriented.

Comment: The formula is false; take $g(x)=x$ and $\sigma=1$. Then the integral is $(b^2-a^2)/2$ rather than $(b-a)/2$.

Comment: @Vladimir , ofcourse. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: integrate by parts:
$$
\int_a^b g^\sigma dg=g^{\sigma+1}(b)-g^{\sigma+1}(a)-\int_a^bgd(g^\sigma)=
g^{\sigma+1}(b)-g^{\sigma+1}(a)-\sigma\int_a^bg^\sigma dg,
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: I know this theorem holds if  $g^\sigma$ is absolutely continuous, but not in this more general case. Again, i know a more general theorem holds (regarding integration by parts) but this question calls for a different, more subtle approach.